# How to update fetched managed objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having troubles in updating a specific record in my core data. What happens in my code is it does change the value but when I rerun the app it goes back to its original value. Why that happens?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Wish" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
// Specify criteria for filtering which objects to fetch
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemWish = %@", self.wishItemStr];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

[fetchedObjects setValue:@"YES" forKeyPath:@"isAchieved"];

if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
    NSLog(@"no fetched objects!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `save` the context.

```
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

I suggest you to read [these very good tutorials and articles on objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/).